# Cypress - cant get content of a span

Tags: angular, cypress

Im trying to check the content of a span containing a calculated price like this:

```
    let currentPrice = ''; 
    cy.get('[data-cy="orgsub-price-span"]', { timeout: 2000 }).then(($ele) => {
      currentPrice = $ele.text();
      cy.log(`'Current Price : ${currentPrice}`);
    });
```

currentPrint always comes out ''.

I can get a value in the browser console:

```
document.querySelector('[data-cy="orgsub-price-span"]').textContent;
```

and I can see the value in the Cypress console.

The angular html is like:

```
  <span data-cy="orgsub-price-span" *ngIf="!calculating">
    {{ (totalCharge - discount + totalTax) }}
  </span>
```

Ive tried sprinkling cy.wait(x) herw and there but that doesn't help.

Anyone got a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is `cy.log()` is evaluating the value of `currentPrice` early, before the `cy.get()` runs.

Defer it by chaining as a sub-command

```js
let currentPrice = ''; 

cy.get('[data-cy="orgsub-price-span"]', { timeout: 2000 })
.then(($ele) => {
  currentPrice = $ele.text();

  cy.log(`Current Price : ${currentPrice}`)  // early evaluation, logs ''
  console.log(`Current Price : ${currentPrice}`) // late evaluation, logs value

  cy.then(() => cy.log(`'Current Price : ${currentPrice}`)); // late evaluation, logs value

  cy.wrap(currentPrice).as('currentPrice')  // save to Cypress alias 
})
.then() => {
  cy.log(`Current Price : ${currentPrice}`)  // late evaluation, logs value
})




// Using currentPrice later

console.log(currentPrice)  // early evaluation, logs ''

cy.then(() => console.log(currentPrice)) // late evaluation, logs value

cy.then(() => cy.log(`'Current Price : ${currentPrice}`)); // late evaluation, logs value


// From alias
cy.get('@currentPrice').then(currentPrice => {
  cy.log(`'Current Price : ${currentPrice}`); // late evaluation, logs value
})
```

Not sure why they do it that way. Obviously `cy.wrap()` needs to do late evaluation because it's purpose is to capture a calculated value but why does `cy.log()` not also do late evaluation.

**Short answer**, don't use `cy.log()` to debug, use `console.log`.

---

**Saving value to `this`**

Use `function` not `() =>`

```js
it('tests current price', function() {

  cy.get('[data-cy="orgsub-price-span"]', { timeout: 2000 })
  .then(function($ele) {
    const currentPrice = $ele.text();
    cy.wrap(currentPrice).as('currentPrice')  // save to Cypress alias 
  })

  // From alias, using `this` 
  cy.log(`Current Price : ${this.currentPrice}`)  // late evaluation, logs value
})
```

Comment: Awsome answer @Paolo.  Thank you!  Helps with my understanding of Cypress a lot.